# loading associated script with content on .load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the most persistant and limiting problem I have known of for a while now with my experience with JQuery.  My problem is simple....

I am using a line of code to load content from html page B to a class defined space in html page A....

```
 $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("musability-music-therapy-what.html .slides");
```

in the class ".slides" (it's a slider) has some associated code to make it run properly....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Store a ref to slides
    var $slides = $(".slides");

    //Bind event to the contianed that gets animated
    $(".slide-container")
    .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        // Remove classes from all the elements within the active container that starts with the class 'add-anim'
        $slides.find(".slide-container [class^='add-anim']").removeClass("animated bounceInLeft bounceInUp");

        //Add appropriate classes to the matched elements within the active container
        var $radio = $slides.find(":radio[name='radio-btn']:checked");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated bounceInUp");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    });
});
```

The code works , the page works if you launch it directly on its own from windows explorer... It doesn't when the .load function gets involved...

**so the question is , How can I have the script loaded not just on that call above (would be a start) but constantly in the index html page I am loading from , (I have other slider functions I will need to use)
In short .load is great to get content but what about the associated code.**

p.s my coding is lame if someone could provide an example of how to do this that would be a-m-a-z-i-n-g ! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this one is sooooo simple i can't beleive it hit me in the face .... simple home truth for Jquery begginners here ...

if you use .load to be smart and grab content from other pages well done....

if any of that content needs a script to run then you need to include $.getScript("url to js file"); after you have done the .load functions

this allows things to simply work !